# Two different versions of Finder in OS X 10.8 after migrating from OS 10.3 Panther

Tags: macos, finder, migration-assistant

While setting up new Mac Mini I checked the option to move files and settings from my old Mac to the new Mac. The old Mac was a 2008 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.3 Panther.

Everything seemed to go well and all my apps copied over to the new machine, but when I open Finder I get the old Finder window, the one from OS X 10.3 Panther. If I open a folder using Spotlight I get an OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Finder window.

How can I fix things so my system only ever uses the Mountain Lion version of Finder?

Comment: Did you move/copy Finder to a non-standard location? How do you open the "old" Finder?

Comment: Wow… You upgraded from 10.3 to 10.8?!

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you managed to install OS 10.3 Panther (which was PowerPC only) on a 2008 MBPro (which is an Intel machine). Certainly none of the PowerPC apps can run on 10.8. What is it you have been trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm sorry i said panter but meant leopard

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fix this is to do a fresh erase and install to Mountain Lion and when you restore from the previous backup, do NOT transfer the settings.  FYI, if you made a "Time Machine" backup you had to be much newer than 10.3.

If this is the case then the backup should be fully compatible.  Just do not put a check mark in the settings box.  I often recommend you also leave out "Other files & folders", but that is your call.

Comment: ok. do i need to make a bootable usb flash drive for mountain lion to do a fresh install?

Comment: No, you can run the fresh install from the restore partition.  Use the disk utility to erase the Macintosh HD partition and then run the installer.  You should be ok.